# My eclipse is not opening.. Why?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been using eclipse from a couple of months and even today morning i worked on a java project but in the evening when i tried to open eclipse.exe, It just showed the loading screen for few seconds and disappeared. Can anybody please tell me the solution?

this is my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

and this is the log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-03-21 22:25:26.046
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:813)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.handleException(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:81)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2412)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the pc?

Comment: Is there more in the log, maybe closer to when it failed to start?

Comment: You probably have a hung process. Go to your task manager and look for a process called javaw.exe and kill it(ONLY if it's the only java based app you have running, and you're *sure* it's the eclipse one!)
Other than that, restart the computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try starting it with -clean, if that doesn't work try deleting .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench. This is what I've seen work on other threads.

Comment: You should link the other threads if they're similar in issue.

Comment: thank you very very very much.. deleting the folder solved my issue

Comment: I had the same issue. I cant find the file .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench. please tell me where can i find it?

Answer (score 2):

I tried deleting items to no avail.

Instead, try this in the command line;

**{path}\eclipse.exe -vm "c:\java\ {installed jdk version} \jre\bin\javaw"**

This worked well for me.