# Eclipse Kepler crashes immediately after its opened

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse Kepler has started crashing up on me right after it is opened(with some logs). It worked until last night.

Last changes made:
Added and deleted some projects
deleted .m2 repo from C:\Users\kate..
Unplanned shutdown few times

OS: Windows 7 64 bit
Eclipse Kepler for 64 bit
JDK: JDK 1.7 64bit

**LOG:**

```
SESSION 2014-08-07 00:04:15.293 eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation 
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product


!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-08-07 00:04:17.787
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.core 4 0 2014-08-07 00:04:18.234
!MESSAGE Could not read metadata for 'D:\kate\MyWorkspace\GIT Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\MyWorkspace\.indexes\properties.index'. Unexpected version: 0.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Could not read metadata for 'D:\kate\MyWorkspace\GIT Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\MyWorkspace\.indexes\properties.index'. Unexpected version: 0.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.Bucket.load(Bucket.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.properties.PropertyBucket.load(PropertyBucket.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.Bucket.load(Bucket.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.BucketTree.loadBucketFor(BucketTree.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.properties.PropertyManager2.getProperty(PropertyManager2.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.getPersistentProperty(Resource.java:1205)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.isShared(RepositoryProvider.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.core.TeamHookDispatcher.getRuleFactory(TeamHookDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Rules.factoryFor(Rules.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Rules.refreshRule(Rules.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1689)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.refresh.RefreshJob.runInWorkspace(RefreshJob.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 567 2014-08-07 00:04:18.236
!MESSAGE Could not read metadata for 'D:\kate\MyWorkspace\GIT Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\MyWorkspace\.indexes\properties.index'. Unexpected version: 0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.core 4 0 2014-08-07 00:04:18.242
!MESSAGE Could not read metadata for 'D:\kate\MyWorkspace\GIT Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\Jenkinsdemo\.indexes\properties.index'. Unexpected version: 0.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Could not read metadata for 'D:\kate\MyWorkspace\GIT Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\Jenkinsdemo\.indexes\properties.index'. Unexpected version: 0.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.Bucket.load(Bucket.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.properties.PropertyBucket.load(PropertyBucket.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.Bucket.load(Bucket.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.BucketTree.loadBucketFor(BucketTree.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.properties.PropertyManager2.getProperty(PropertyManager2.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.getPersistentProperty(Resource.java:1205)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.isShared(RepositoryProvider.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.core.TeamHookDispatcher.getRuleFactory(TeamHookDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Rules.factoryFor(Rules.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Rules.refreshRule(Rules.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1689)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.refresh.RefreshJob.runInWorkspace(RefreshJob.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 567 2014-08-07 00:04:18.242
!MESSAGE Could not read metadata for 'D:\kate\MyWorkspace\GIT Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\Jenkinsdemo\.indexes\properties.index'. Unexpected version: 0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.core 4 0 2014-08-07 00:04:18.246
!MESSAGE Could not read metadata for 'D:\kate\MyWorkspace\GIT Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\GoogleTestAutomation\.indexes\properties.index'. Unexpected version: 0.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Could not read metadata for 'D:\kate\MyWorkspace\GIT Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\GoogleTestAutomation\.indexes\properties.index'. Unexpected version: 0.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.Bucket.load(Bucket.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.properties.PropertyBucket.load(PropertyBucket.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.Bucket.load(Bucket.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.BucketTree.loadBucketFor(BucketTree.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.properties.PropertyManager2.getProperty(PropertyManager2.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.getPersistentProperty(Resource.java:1205)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.isShared(RepositoryProvider.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.core.TeamHookDispatcher.getRuleFactory(TeamHookDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Rules.factoryFor(Rules.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Rules.refreshRule(Rules.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1689)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.refresh.RefreshJob.runInWorkspace(RefreshJob.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 567 2014-08-07 00:04:18.246
!MESSAGE Could not read metadata for 'D:\kate\MyWorkspace\GIT Projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\GoogleTestAutomation\.indexes\properties.index'. Unexpected version: 0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-08-07 00:04:21.040
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.internal.legacyconversion.LegacyProjectChecker.earlyStartup(LegacyProjectChecker.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-08-07 00:04:21.043
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.internal.legacyconversion.LegacyProjectChecker.earlyStartup(LegacyProjectChecker.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-08-07 00:04:21.045
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logging(PlatformLogWriter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.log(RuntimeLog.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-08-07 00:04:21.046
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-08-07 00:04:21.047
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-08-07 00:04:21.047
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.handleException(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven 4 0 2014-08-07 00:04:21.048
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.internal.legacyconversion.LegacyProjectChecker.earlyStartup(LegacyProjectChecker.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven 4 0 2014-08-07 00:04:21.048
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.internal.legacyconversion.LegacyProjectChecker.earlyStartup(LegacyProjectChecker.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-08-07 00:04:21.049
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.handleException(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

**ECLIPSE.INI**

```
 #This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Tue Jul 08 19:48:21 IST 2014
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.400.v20130327-2119.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.I20130319-1000.jar
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate your help on this. I had almost lots of settings and plugins installed to it though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was resolved by following the below given solution as I found in this thread.

[My eclipse is not opening.. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566366/my-eclipse-is-not-opening-why?rq=1)

Step 1 : Try starting it with -clean, if that doesn't work 
Step 2 : Try deleting .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench.

Answer (score 5):

Start your eclipse with by providing clean flag

```
./eclipse.exe -clean
```

Comment: Hi Prashant, This time eclipse start logo stayed for a while and still crashed. I mean to say it never even opened the workbench

Comment: Did you pass 'clean' flag or '-clean' you suppose to pass '-clean' flag, I am also updating my answer. as well make sure you have already deleted the .metadata folder from your default or old workspace.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by deleting the following folder  **org.eclipse.e4.workbench** from .metadata\.plugins. I appreciate your help though :)

Comment: @JavaLover it would be really good if you posted that as a solution, for the benefit of anyone having this problem in the future.

Comment: If JavaLover is correct, then the -clean flag does not clean up the .metadata folder.  If that doesn't do it, I would delete the entire workspace .metadata folder and restart Eclipse so it needs to regenerate all your settings.